# Array output for a single value

Tags: php, arrays, json

The array:

```
Array
(
[2010091907] => Array
    (
        [home] => Array
            (
                [score] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 7
                        [2] => 17
                        [3] => 10
                        [4] => 7
                        [5] => 0
                        [T] => 41
                    )

                [abbr] => ATL
                [to] => 2
            )
```

How would I access abbr and display its value.  Here's my PHP code:

```
     $json=json_decode($data,true);

     foreach ($json as $key => $date) {
         echo "Key: ".$key."; Value: ".$date."<br />";
         foreach ($date as $team) {
             echo "Team: ".$team."<br />";

         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $array[2010091907]['home']['abbr'];
```

would output

```
ATL
```

if you want to output just the singl value. Within your loop structure, JochenJung's got the fix below.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `$team['abbr']`

in your inner foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://codepad.org/UoY8oaKY):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $date) {
    echo "Key: ".$key."; Value: ".$date."<br />";
         foreach ($date as $team) {
             echo "Team: ".$team['abbr'];
         }     
}
```